# WPF Control Template bind to Child Control

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, controls

In a TreeViewItem control template I need to bind a visual state to a child control but I cannot figure out the binding syntax.

In the TreeView's HierarchicalDataTemplate I have:

```
       <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imgPicture" Source=".."/>                      
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to bind a visual state animation to imgPicture in the control template.

In the TreeViewItem's control template I have:

```
<VisualState Name="Selected">
     <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header}" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight"
To="100"
Duration="0"/>
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But the Storyboard.TargetName binds to the StackPanel (since that is the header of the TreeViewItem), and I need it to bind to the control inside the StackPanel (the imgPicture) so that I can change the control's property. Is there a way that I can do this by using the xaml binding syntax? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Doesn`t `Storyboard.TargetName="imgPicture"` work?

Comment: I tried Storyboard.TargetName="imgPicture", but it returned the exception: 'imgPicture' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Binding by using the ElementName property (imgPicture) or set the Storyboard.TargetName to imgPicture.

Comment: I tried Storyboard.TargetName="imgPicture", but it returned the exception: 'imgPicture' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'.  Also tried setting the ElementName but it does not work.